# How to merge two tables if they have relation one to many in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to join two tables, on column `date, MediaSource, country`. But I have one cost for country per date per MediaSource while having many ltv values for country per date per MediaSource.

How could I join them properly?
Here is the result that I want:

```
Date        country     MediaSource   Cost  LTV  user_Id
01.02.2020  UK                FB      500   23   4234
01.02.2020  UK                FB      500   21   3
01.02.2020  US                FB      400   32   231
01.02.2020  US                FB      400   432  213
02.02.2020  US                FB      400   32   44
01.02.2020  UK              Youtube   600   13   3
01.02.2020  UK              Youtube   600   5    24324
01.03.2020  RO                FB      500   324  324
01.03.2020  RO                FB      500   64   325
01.03.2020  BR              Youtube   600   24   32423
01.03.2020  BR              Youtube   600   34   232
01.03.2020  BR              Youtube   600   5    1231
01.03.2020  BR              Youtube   600   1    321
```

And here is two dataframe that I have
With LTV:

```
user_Id   Date      country      MediaSource    LTV
44       01.02.2020  US               FB        5
213      01.02.2020  US               FB        432
231      01.02.2020  US               FB        32
4234     01.02.2020  UK               FB        23
4234     01.02.2020  UK               FB        3
3        01.02.2020  UK               Youtube   13
24324    01.02.2020  UK               Youtube   5
325      01.03.2020  RO               FB        64
324      01.03.2020  RO               FB        324
32423    01.03.2020  BR               Youtube   24
232      01.03.2020  BR               Youtube   34
1231     01.03.2020  BR               Youtube   5
321      01.03.2020  BR               Youtube   1
```

With Cost:

```
Date      country   MediaSource     cost
01.02.2020  US       FB             400
01.02.2020  UK       FB             500
01.02.2020  UK       Youtube        600
01.03.2020  RO       FB             500
01.03.2020  BR       Youtube        600
```

Comment: I don't get your logic for merging the dataframes. Can you explain it a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a merge

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m.%d.%Y')
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m.%d.%Y')
df_merge = pd.merge(df, df1, how = 'left', on = ['Date', 'MediaSource', 'country'])
df_merge
```

Comment: It had not worked out for me, as it writes different costs for every user

Comment: You did not include cost in your original expected results, can you please add a column with the cost/user_ID if those are also required for your code? (preferably code that is in pythonic form not a screenshot)

Comment: sure, please give me 2 minutes

Comment: I updated it, tried to make in best form as I could

Comment: is this form of data okay?

Comment: Yes let me take a look

Comment: In your expected results did you swtich the user_id and the LTV columns?

Comment: I just added  user_Id column to expected results and changed values ln LTV dataframe

Comment: I'm looking over your expected results and your different dataframes and it looks like your data is dirty. I believe my code does exactly what is requested, but since the data is incorrect between df1 and df2 and your expected results

Comment: Could you please explain where it is dirty?

Comment: Or could I send you my Kaggle notebook so you would see all data?

Comment: 01.02.2020  US FB 400 0 213 in expected results and 213 01.02.2020 US FB 432 in df1 they have different values. I would rather not use Kaggle since I don't want to download anything (even from kaggle)

Comment: let me re-edit it